# res.send возвращает [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, асинхронность, promise

хочу отренедрить разметку, после получения данных из fetch,
при попытке отправить разметку, отправляется [object Promise]

```
const express = require("express");
const async = require("express-async-await");
const app = express();
const fetch = require("node-fetch");


async function mapData(url) {
    const res = await fetch(url)
    const data = await res.json()
    return data.map(i => {
        return 
                `
                <item turbo="true">
                    <link>${i.url_node}</link>
                    <turbo:content>
                        <header>
                            <figure>
                                <img src="${i.photo}" />
                            </figure>
                            <h1>${i.title}</h1>
                        </header>
                        ${i.body}
                    </turbo:content>
                </item>
                `
    });
}

app.get("/", function(req, res){

  res.send(`${mapData('https://sasasa.ru/json/news_feed/')}`);

});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Пожалуйста, опишите подробнее, в чем проблема?

Comment: Правильно, потому что `mapData` возвращает `Promise`. Попробуйте добавить `await`, например `${await mapData('https://sasasa.ru/json/news_feed/')}`

Comment: вот так работает
app.get("/", async function(req, res){

  res.send(`${await mapsData()}`);

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Асинхронная функция по умолчанию возвращает промис. Если в самой функции возвращается какое-то значение, то это значение просто попадает в промис.

```
async function foo() {
  return 10
}

foo().then(console.log); // 10
```

Поэтому нужно использовать `await`, он дождется резолва промиса и вернет именно значение

```
async function foo() {
  return 10
}

const result = await foo();
console.log(result);
```